# Javascript: variable scope in callback

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

I'm trying to re-use `variable` inside a `function` that calls a `callback`, but it does not work the way I think it should;

```
another()(); //=> logs "somevalue"
callingfn(); //=> logs " someval is not defined"

function a(fn){
  var someval = "some-value";
  return fn();
} 

function callingfn(){
 return a.call(this, function(){
   console.log(someval)
  })
}

function another(){
  var sv = "somevalue";
  return function(){
    console.log(sv);
  }
}
```

I'm not able to understand if this is closure-related problem, but at first I expected that `someval` in `callingfn` would have been defined.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `someval` is local to the function `a()` and will be accessible only inside `a()` and any closures inside `a()` (there are none in the code you posted).

Comment: Uhm, right. I was wondering if there was a way to make the callback a closure in `a()`

Comment: Thats not possible, for it to be a callback it has to be defined inside `a()`

Answer (score 6):

function `fn()` is different from `a()` though it receives `fn` as parameter.

You could possibly send `someval` as parameter.

```
another()(); //=> logs "somevalue"
callingfn(); //=> logs " someval is not defined"

function a(fn){
  var someval = "some-value";
  return fn(someval);
} 

function callingfn(){
 return a.call(this, function(someval){
   console.log(someval)
  })
}

function another(){
  var sv = "somevalue";
  return function(){
    console.log(sv);
  }
}
```

Or simply declare the `var someval` as global scope, currently it is inside a function which makes it local.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
another()(); //=> logs "somevalue"
callingfn(); //=> logs " someval is not defined"
var someval;
var sv;

function a(fn){
  someval = "some-value";
  return fn();
} 

function callingfn(){
 return a.call(this, function(){
   console.log(someval)
  })
}

function another(){
 sv = "somevalue";
  return function(){
    console.log(sv);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `someval` outside the scope of the functions:

```
var someval; // <- outside of the scope of any one function
another()(); //=> logs "somevalue"
callingfn(); //=> logs " someval is not defined"

function a(fn){
  someval = "some-value"; // <-remove "var" to access the variable outside the scope
  return fn();
} 

function callingfn(){
 return a.call(this, function(){
   console.log(someval)
  })
}

function another(){
  var sv = "somevalue";
  return function(){
    console.log(sv);
  }
}
```